# Browser's progress bar not visible when I click on a link on my next.js (react) app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, progress-bar

I'm developping an app with Strapi as a backend and Next.js as a front-end.

In my frontend I have many links. They all are "syntaxed" like these exemples below.
The problem is, on my browsers (Desktop and mobile) when I click on a link it doesn't show that the browser is charging the page but the page appears 2 seconds later.
It will make an user think the website doesn't work.

How can I correct that ?
It would  be nice to have the probress bar /circle  showing like this exemple:

[Circle progress bar exemple on another website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCtjQ.png)

```html
<Box key={sectionPart.id} mx={20} className={`button button-${sectionPart.style}`}>
    <Link href={sectionPart.url} >
        <Box as="a">
            {sectionPart.title}
        </Box>
    </Link>
</Box>
```

```html
        //snipet of menu navigation
    

<Link key={retrieveLinkId(link)} /*href={link.url}*/ href="/">
                                                    
       <a  className={router.pathname === retrieveLinkUrl(link) ? 'active' : ''}>
             <Flex justifyContent="start" className="featured-content" >

                  {/*** featured content Image **/}
                <Box className="link-featured-image-container">
                   <Image className="link-featured-image" 
                          src={retrieveLinkFeatureImg(link)} 
                          width={120} 
                          height={120} 
                    />
                 </Box>

                  {/*** featured content title & button  ***/}
                  <Box className="featured-content-links">
                     <Flex justifyContent="start" alignItems="start">
                        <p className="dropdown-section-item-title"> 
                          {retrieveLinkLabel(link)}
                        </p>
                     </Flex>

                     <Flex className="dropdown-section-cta" alignItems="flex-end">
                        <p>
                          {retrieveLinkFeatureBtn(link)}
                        </p>
                      </Flex>
                  </Box>

              </Flex>
          </a>
       </Link>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, [Nprogress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nprogress) to have a progress bar during route navigation. Place the code below in your root app file

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';
import NProgress from 'nprogress';


Router.onRouteChangeStart = () => {
  NProgress.start();
};

Router.onRouteChangeComplete = () => {
  NProgress.done();
};

Router.onRouteChangeError = () => {
  // hanlde the rror
  NProgress.done();
};
```

See the configuration section in the NProgress readme for addition config, if you want to add more functionality to it

Answer (score 0):

Using @Utkarsh's answer, NProgress package, in recent versions of next.js, the below code should work. Add in `_app.tsx`.

```
import NProgress from "nprogress";
import "nprogress/nprogress.css";
```

```
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const start = () => NProgress.start();
    const stop = () => NProgress.done();

    // Listen to route change events
    Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", start);
    Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", stop);
    Router.events.on("routeChangeError", stop);

    // Clean up event listeners
    return () => {
      Router.events.off("routeChangeStart", start);
      Router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", stop);
      Router.events.off("routeChangeError", stop);
    };
  }, []);
```